Дублируется окно cmd при открытии терминала
Вроде ничего критичного, но немного раздражает и решил исправить, но не нашел как!
Вроде и гуглил и в настройках смотрел, подскажите как исправить, кто знает?

Должно быть что-ото типо этого:

В итоге я сижу как окно в окне, как мне убрать это?

win+R, написать powershell,  Enter? Я правильно понял?

@user7860670  так у меня тоже приложение терминала

@Oopss вы про другое, я понимаю что я могу просто запустить powershell отдельно,  я запускаю именно через терминал, но он открывает еще в одном окне

Я просто был невнимателен, там есть этот пункт в настройках:

Параметры -> Оформление -> Скрытый заголовок -> перезапуск.

